# GRIB2 data on a Google Map

Tags: dictionary, gdal, weather

I would like to display Grib2 data on a Google Map, the data is radar data from Canada Weather or NOAA. I have tried using gdal_translate with little success. Any ideas?

All the best,
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used Google Map for something like that, but I have spent a lot of time reading and writing GRIB2 data.
You can use wgrib2 utility or GRIB_API/GRIB TOOLS to read GRIB2 data you have, and write some code to put in correct format, to be usable with Google Map.

Check these out:

https://software.ecmwf.int/wiki/display/GRIB/Home

http://www.cpc.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib2/